# Are CCK shared fields loaded on node_load()?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

`field_metatitle` is a CCK field that is used amongst 5 different content types, meaning that it is a "shared field". When I do `$node = node_load('123');`, I see that $node->field_metatitle is not present.

Comment: What type of CCK field is this? For normal fields, they should definitely be attached to the object on load (See the two functions I linked below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They definitely should be attached to the node object via [`content_nodeapi()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content.module/function/content_nodeapi/6) and [`content_load()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--cck--content.module/function/content_load/6).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the two functions, I will definitely put a break point in them!

Comment: They are indeed added thru `node_load` and the CCK functions you mentioned. It just happens that `content_load()` caches it's results in a table defined by `content_cache_tablename()`. Running `drush cc all` only clears the general cache, and not the table defined by `content_cache_tablename()`. Clearing the cache thru the Drupal admin page instead of the command line after adding CCK fields solves the problem.

Comment: Are you positive about the cache thing?  `drush cc all` calls [drupal_flush_all_caches](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_flush_all_caches/6), which in turn invokes `hook_flush_caches` to get additional table names.  content.module does have this hook, which returns `content_cache_tablename()`  The default clear cache from the admin menu module and the performance setting page also eventually calls the same function via [system_clear_cache_submit](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/system_clear_cache_submit/6).

Comment: This question is supposed to pertain to Drupal 7, so are these answers really applicable? I'm not getting this behavior at all in Drupal 7. With my database converted from D6 to D7, if I use node_load I don't get any of the CCK fields from the original database. However I do see them in the content_migrate module, so Drupal certainly /could/ be loading them. What - if anything additional - do I need for D7 to be able to load these fields? The functions content_load and content_nodeapi don't exist in D7, and the D7 cck module doesn't supply any equivalents, as far as I can tell.